# How to handle <br> tags in HTMLCleaner?

Tags: android, htmlcleaner

While parsing with HTMLCleaner all "br" tags are being ignored. I would like to know how i can handle "br" tags.

Here is the an example:

```
<p>El tenista suizo <b>Roger Federer</b>, número dos del mundo.<br><br>
"Quiero todavía seguir ganando títulos, por eso deseo mantenerme al tope de mi capacidad
física porque quiero seguir jugando varios años más. Aspiro a seguir en el centro
de las canchas jugando Grand Slams", aseguró el suizo en entrevista con Caracol radio.<br><br></p>
```

The output is the br tags getting cleaned.

Any ideas? Please i need help.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

normally in the XHTML syntax, the "br" tag is written `<br/>` and not `<br>`

maybe the cleaner does not recognize the tags written like `<br>` and cleans them.

hope it helps

Comment: The data im trying to get comes from this [website](http://www.eluniverso.com)
The article im aiming for is this [one](http://www.eluniverso.com/2012/11/28/1/1442/roger-federer-quiero-seguir-ganando-titulos.html)

Comment: I found that htmlcleaner cleans all empty tags no matter which they are. I tried your suggestion but no luck.
Here is the code for transforming br tag to /br:
CleanerTransformations transformations = new CleanerTransformations();  
TagTransformation tt =  new TagTransformation("br", "/br", true); 
transformations.addTransformation(tt);
cleaner.setTransformations(transformations);

Comment: You can try formatting the html code to replace "br" tags by "\n" which does a new line as "br" tag